# Why is PLINQ slower than for loop?

Tags: c#, linq, task-parallel-library

Let's say I have these two methods:

```
public BigInteger PFactorial(int n)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(1, n)
                     .AsParallel()
                     .Select(i => (BigInteger)i)
                     .Aggregate(BigInteger.One, BigInteger.Multiply);
}

public BigInteger Factorial(int n)
{
    BigInteger result = BigInteger.One;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        result *= i;
    return result;
 }
```

The following were the results I got:

```
PFactorial(25000) -> 0,9897 seconds
Factorial(25000) -> 0,9252 seconds
```

I understand that PLINQ has some overhead because of the threads setup, but with such a big `n` I was expecting PLINQ to be faster.

Here is another result:

```
PFactorial(50000) -> 4,91035 seconds
Factorial(50000) -> 4,40056 seconds
```

Comment: And this is why we benchmark.  Rather than guessing at how much is gained by parallelizing something, you should test it, so you'll know for sure.  And of course keep in mind that aggregation can be parallelied, but not nearly as effectively as other types of operations (such as projections).

Comment: The `Aggregate` doesn’t happen in parallel.

Comment: `Enumerable.Range` will cause some additional time as well...

Comment: Why did someone vote to close this for unclarity?  What is unclear about his question?  It's perfectly valid.

Comment: @MatiasCicero: I’m going to bring it back in the hopes that someone can point out where I’m going wrong here. I had thought you would need [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd384149%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to usefully parallelize aggregation, and looking at the usual one again, I don’t understand how a `Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate>` could ever be applied in parallel unless it assumes that the operation is associative when `TSource` is `TAccumulate`, which seems wrong somehow…

Comment: @Servy [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963547.aspx) do say: "PLINQ is usually the recommended approach whenever you need to apply the parallel aggregation pattern to .NET applications"

Comment: @Magnus Yes.  And?  If the proper way to do the operation in parallel is slower then doing it serially then *you shouldn't be doing it in parallel*, and should just do it serially.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<s>Parallel is not really possible with aggregate. At least i cant imagine that in my mind. Any way,</s> You should make parallelization possible by dividing your list into chunks. Find those results. and finally multiply chunks. Here is the fast way of PLinq.

```
static public BigInteger PFactorial(int n)
{
    var range = Enumerable.Range(1, n).Select(x => (BigInteger) x).AsParallel();
    var lists = range.GroupBy(x => x/(n/Environment.ProcessorCount)).Select(x => x.AsEnumerable());
    var results = lists.Select(x => x.Aggregate(BigInteger.One, BigInteger.Multiply));
    var result = results.Aggregate(BigInteger.One, BigInteger.Multiply);
    return result;
}
```

Test

```
PFactorial(50000) -> 1,41 seconds
Factorial(50000) -> 2,69 seconds
```

Edit: As mentioned by Servy and Chatzigiannakis if you dont use seed it can perfectly use parallelization and you get pretty much same results as above (a bit faster).

```
return Enumerable.Range(1,n).Select(x => (BigInteger)x).AsParallel().Aggregate(BigInteger.Multiply);
```

Comment: `Aggregate` can *absolutely* do its work in parallel, just not when there's a seed.  It of course parallelizes the work in much the same way that you're doing it, namely breaking the work up into chunks, aggregating those in parallel, and then combing the intermediate results.

Comment: I have tried without using seed. I still got same result as normal Factorial. Any way thanks for the information. Ill look in to it. @Servy

Comment: `ParallelEnumerable.Aggregate` internally distinguishes between associative and non-associative aggregation functions and runs the former in parallel. When left unspecified, I believe it assumes associative (and commutative).

Comment: Oops. Well i dont know why i got that results without seed. I think i need more coffee. Thanks @Servy

Answer (score 1):

Please do not assume that pLinQ is always faster than LinQ. PLinQ execution time based on many condition

Use PLinQ only when there are more elements and have some CPU intensive query. I'll suggest to use  `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)` in a function to emulate the CPU load as cycle delay and then call that function from LinQ and PlinQ for 10000 times. Then you can see the difference. Please find [sample here](http://www.totaldotnet.com/sub/code-to-implement-plinq-c-4-0)

Your current function Factorial actually not doing any CPU intensive task and reason PLinQ taking more time, because it dived the query to run in multiple core and consolidate the result of individual core to single output, which take little more time then normal.

Also make sure you are using multi core processors (minimum 4 will give you good analysis)

Comment: *“Your current function Factorial actually not doing any CPU intensive task”* Um… yes, it is.

Comment: @minitech It's not - it's just multiplying some numbers together, which seem to average (4900ms/50000) 0.098ms a multiplication.  For Parallel to realize any gains, particularly considering all the work it has to do to figure out batching, start-up threads, dealing with all the wrapping etc it's not that great a task.

Comment: @NPSF3000: As proven by the accepted answer, it can realize gains.